# How do I use SCNShaderModifierEntryPointGeometry?

Tags: swift, xcode, shader, scenekit

I am trying to learn how to animate the SCNShaderModifierEntryPointGeometry to move the texture across the SCNPlane.

To try and understand it, I found some example code on a previous question:

[Using shader modifiers to animate texture in SceneKit leads to jittery textures over time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28886111/using-shader-modifiers-to-animate-texture-in-scenekit-leads-to-jittery-textures)

Here is the example inserted into code:

```
    super.init()
    self.geometry = SCNPlane(width: 1, height: 1)

    self.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named:"art.scnassets/cloud.png")

    let mTrans =  SCNMatrix4MakeTranslation(0, 0, 0)
    let mScale = SCNMatrix4MakeScale(1, 1, 1)
    self.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contentsTransform = SCNMatrix4Mult(mTrans, mScale)

    self.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.wrapS = SCNWrapMode.repeat
    self.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.wrapT = SCNWrapMode.repeat

    self.geometry?.firstMaterial?.shaderModifiers = @{ SCNShaderModifierEntryPointGeometry : @"_geometry.texcoords[0] = vec2((_geometry.texcoords[0].x+floor(u_time*30.0))/10.0, (_geometry.texcoords[0].y+floor(u_time*30.0/10.0))/7.0);" };
```

The intended result is the cloud texture animating across the plane

[image: cloud]

The error message says:

Replace 'SCNShaderModifierEntryPointGeometry' with 'SCNShaderModifierEntryPoint.geometry'

but I checked apple documentation and it exists:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnshadermodifierentrypointgeometry?language=objc

Thanks for reading.

Comment: [I found this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29462745/how-to-create-an-animated-texture-in-scenekit-fallback-on-default-program-err?rq=1) after posting the question and it seems this line of code: myMaterial.shaderModifiers = [ SCNShaderModifierEntryPointGeometry : "uniform float u_time; _geometry.texcoords[0] = vec2((_geometry.texcoords[0].x+floor(u_time*30.0))/24.0, (_geometry.texcoords[0].y+floor(u_time*30.0/24.0))/1.0);" ] works if I replace 'SCNShaderModifierEntryPointGeometry' with 'SCNShaderModifierEntryPoint.geometry' but it sadly now I have the same jitter problem.

Comment: sadly it only animates while the Plane or Camera moves**