# scene kit animate texture

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, scenekit

I am trying to reproduce SKAction.animate(with: sprites, timePerFrame: 0.5) behaviour on a SCNNode and I don't know how to do it. Here is the SCNNode creation :

```
var fishNode: SCNNode = {
    let plane = SCNPlane(width: 0.1, height: 0.1)
    plane.firstMaterial!.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "fish_idle_1_\(GameManager.selectedFishSkin+1)")
    let node = SCNNode(geometry: plane)
    node.constraints = [SCNBillboardConstraint()]
    return node
}()
```

As it looks like SCNAction does not provide texture animation API, should I instantiate a Timer that recomputes the node geometry every 0.5 sec or is there a way to use the animation API ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/28889045/2997825

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I don't know on which object I should apply the shader to. Could you please provide some context ? I don't know that much about sprite sheets. I tried : plane.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = SKTextureAtlas(named: "Sprites") ; plane.firstMaterial?.shaderModifiers = [SCNShaderModifierEntryPoint.geometry: "_geometry.texcoords[0] = vec2((_geometry.texcoords[0].x+floor(mod(1 * u_time, 2) / 2))/10.0, (_geometry.texcoords[0].y+floor((mod(1 * u_time, 2) / 2))/10.0))/7.0);"] where SKTextureAtlas has 2 images sheet1 and sheet2, I only see a white/pink square moving.